# How do I use OAuth to connect to the Tumblr API in C#?

Tags: c#, oauth, tumblr

I'm trying to develop a C# simple application to interact with [Tumblr v2 APIs](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#auth).
I want to post photos & texts on Tumblr.

I found this librairy 
RestSharp : https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/oAuth1Tests.cs

DevDefined.OAuth - an OAuth consumer and provider implementation for .Net : http://code.google.com/p/devdefined-tools/wiki/OAuth

I can not do Tumblr authentication using OAuth correctly.
Does anyone have a fully working example in C# that shows how this works?

Thanks.

Comment: Hélas, NO ! I don't solve this problem.